# How to convert this Microsoft SQL query into a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I used this query to get particular result from a Microsoft SQL Server table, but now I need to convert this query into MySQL query. I don't know how to do that.

```
SELECT TOP 3 COUNT(Item1) AS ITEM_COUNT,Item1
FROM [cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE [Type] = 'Adidas'  and [Age]='25'
GROUP BY Item1
ORDER BY ITEM_COUNT DESC
```

Comment: did you try running that?

Comment: We really like people to have made an effort prior to asking questions, and to show that in their post. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(Item1) AS ITEM_COUNT,Item1
FROM Suggetion_DB
WHERE Type = 'Adidas'  and Age='25'
GROUP BY Item1
ORDER BY ITEM_COUNT DESC
limit 3
```